# Different types of posts for Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I create two types of posts in Gatsby JS. I have blog articles and projects. I am using this instruction - https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/tutorial/part-6/. The bottom line is that this approach of creating, for example, a blog does not require the use of a file `gatsby-node.js`.

By analogy, I decided that I would add to `gatsby-config.js` settings for projects

```
        {
            resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
            options: {
                name: `blog`,
                path: `${__dirname}/blog`,
            }
        },
        {
            resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
            options: {
                name: `projects`,
                path: `${__dirname}/projects`,
            }
        },
```

Then I will create a Projects folder next to the Blog folder and recreate a structure like this in it

```
pages
    |___blog
    |      |___{mdx.frontmatter__slug}.js
    |      |___index.js    
    |
    |___projects
           |___{mdx.frontmatter__slug}.js
           |___index.js
```

And I thought that everything would work for me. The problem is that the site itself works in the `develop` mode, but when you do `gatsby build`, then errors are issued all the time. My approach is fundamentally wrong in something. In what?

In order not to copy the code of my files here, I opened a repo - https://github.com/leokolt/schtml/.

Here is an error that occurs when building a project, while everything works in development mode. Gatsby is trying to create a yet-another-post page under the projects type, although it belongs to the blog type.

```
ERROR 

Page data from page-data.json for the failed page "/projects/yet-another-post/": {
  "componentChunkName":
"component---src-pages-projects-mdx-frontmatter-slug-js-content-file-path-c-gatsby-schtml-blog-third-post-index-mdx",
  "path": "/projects/yet-another-post/",
  "result": {
    "data": {
      "mdx": null
    },
    "pageContext": {
      "id": "74425280-1f4a-54bc-b4dd-029579178280",
      "frontmatter__slug": "yet-another-post",
      "__params": {
        "frontmatter__slug": "yet-another-post"
      },
      "frontmatter": {
        "title": "Yet Another Post",
        "date": "2021-07-25",
        "slug": "yet-another-post",
        "tags": [
          "animals",
          "Chicago",
          "zoos"
        ],
        "categories": [
          "GatsbyJS",
          "Gatsby Develop",
          "Сайт с нуля"
        ],
        "posttype": "blog",
        "featuredImage": "./third.jpg"
      }
    }
  },
  "staticQueryHashes": [
    "3764592887"
  ]
}

failed Building static HTML for pages - 6.819s

 ERROR #95313 

Building static HTML failed for path "/projects/yet-another-post/"

See our docs page for more info on this error: https://gatsby.dev/debug-html





  WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'frontmatter' of null

  - {mdx.frontmatter__slug}.js:22 
    webpack:/schtml/src/pages/projects/{mdx.frontmatter__slug}.js:22:19

  - emotion-styled-base.esm.js:1 
    [schtml]/[@emotion]/styled/base/dist/emotion-styled-base.esm.js:1:59

  - emotion-styled-base.esm.js:4 
    [schtml]/[@emotion]/styled/base/dist/emotion-styled-base.esm.js:4:50

  - {mdx.frontmatter__slug}.js:26 
    schtml/src/pages/projects/{mdx.frontmatter__slug}.js:26:10

  - emotion-styled-base.esm.js:4 
    [schtml]/[@emotion]/styled/base/dist/emotion-styled-base.esm.js:4:50

  - {mdx.frontmatter__slug}.js:26 
    schtml/src/pages/projects/{mdx.frontmatter__slug}.js:26:10

  - index.js:62 
    [schtml]/[camelcase]/index.js:62:1

  - {mdx.frontmatter__slug}.js:26 
    schtml/src/pages/projects/{mdx.frontmatter__slug}.js:26:10

  - emotion-styled-base.esm.js:5 
    [schtml]/[@emotion]/styled/base/dist/emotion-styled-base.esm.js:5:65

  - {mdx.frontmatter__slug}.js:26 
    schtml/src/pages/projects/{mdx.frontmatter__slug}.js:26:10

  - emotion-styled-base.esm.js:4 
    [schtml]/[@emotion]/styled/base/dist/emotion-styled-base.esm.js:4:50

  - {mdx.frontmatter__slug}.js:26 
    schtml/src/pages/projects/{mdx.frontmatter__slug}.js:26:10

  - emotion-styled-base.esm.js:2 
    [schtml]/[@emotion]/styled/base/dist/emotion-styled-base.esm.js:2:32

  - emotion-styled-base.esm.js:4 
    [schtml]/[@emotion]/styled/base/dist/emotion-styled-base.esm.js:4:50

  - {mdx.frontmatter__slug}.js:26 
    schtml/src/pages/projects/{mdx.frontmatter__slug}.js:26:10

  - index.js:62 
    [schtml]/[camelcase]/index.js:62:1
```

Comment: I don't see any `{mdx.frontmatter__slug}.js` under  `/projects` folder as you mentioned

Comment: Hi. I added a folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same way I reccomended you in [Crate Tag & Category taxonomy in Gatsby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73517436/crate-tag-category-taxonomy-in-gatsby) your approach will become far way easiest if you add a `key` value to your markdowns in order to filter which type of data are you querying. Otherwise, your GraphQL query won't be able to infer the type of data (project or post) you are fetching because the query is exactly the same and at the same level.

Given the same [project sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73517436/crate-tag-category-taxonomy-in-gatsby) you have:

```
---
title: "First Work"
date: "2021-08-28"
slug: "first-work"
posttype: projects
---
```

You can take advantage of `posttype` creating a file like:

```
{mdx.frontmatter__variant}/{mdx.slug}.js
```

To create specific queries and pages for each variant, since `posttype` will become the first nested level

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answers to my questions forced me to search more thoroughly and I found the answers)

Answer (score -1):

For example, I realized that React is swearing at my post output files, where I list all the tags and categories that relate to posts but do not relate to projects. So I found this solution: instead of

```
<div>{tags
                .map(tag => tag.trim())
                .filter(tag => tag.length > 0)
                .map(tag => <ul key={tag}><Link to={`/blog/tag/${_.kebabCase(transliterate(tag))}`}>{tag}</Link></ul>)}
            </div>
```

i use

```
<div>{tags && tags
                .map(tag => tag.trim())
                .filter(tag => tag.length > 0)
                .map(tag => <ul key={tag}><Link to={`/blog/tag/${_.kebabCase(transliterate(tag))}`}>{tag}</Link></ul>)}
            </div>
```

This extra `tags &&` does a great job at the beginning and does a check for tags in the post.

I also turned to the Gatsby Router API, as advised [Ferran Buireu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5585371/ferran-buireu). Thanks to this, I created folder in the `/pages` folder `{mdx.frontmatter__type}` inside which I put the template file of my posts `{mdx.fields__slug}.js` and now Gatsby is not trying to create project pages for my blog posts, and blog posts for projects.